# How to read parquet files using `ssc.fileStream()`? What are the types passed to `ssc.fileStream()`?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop2

My understanding of Spark's `fileStream()` method is that it takes three types as parameters: `Key`, `Value`, and `Format`. In case of text files, the appropriate types are: `LongWritable`, `Text`, and `TextInputFormat`.

**First**, I want to understand the nature of these types. Intuitively, I would guess that the `Key` in this case is the line number of the file, and the `Value` is the text on that line. So, in the following example of a text file:

```
Hello
Test
Another Test
```

The first row of the `DStream` would have a `Key` of `1` (`0`?) and a `Value` of `Hello`.

Is this correct?

**Second part of my question**: I looked at the decompiled implementation of `ParquetInputFormat` and I noticed something curious:

```
public class ParquetInputFormat<T>
       extends FileInputFormat<Void, T> {
//...

public class TextInputFormat
       extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>
       implements JobConfigurable {
//...
```

`TextInputFormat` extends `FileInputFormat` of types `LongWritable` and `Text`, whereas `ParquetInputFormat` extends the same class of types `Void` and `T`.

Does this mean that I must create a `Value` class to hold an entire row of my parquet data, and then pass the types `<Void, MyClass, ParquetInputFormat<MyClass>>` to `ssc.fileStream()`?

If so, how should I implement `MyClass`?

**EDIT 1**: I have noticed a `readSupportClass` which is to be passed to `ParquetInputFormat` objects. What kind of class is this, and how is it used to parse the parquet file? Is there some documentation that covers this?

**EDIT 2**: As far as I can tell, this is **impossible**. If anybody knows how to stream in parquet files to Spark then please feel free to share...

Comment: [Please don't annotate edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My sample to read parquet files in Spark Streaming is below.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.read.support.class", "parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport")
val stream = ssc.fileStream[Void, GenericRecord, ParquetInputFormat[GenericRecord]](
  directory, { path: Path => path.toString.endsWith("parquet") }, true, ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

val lines = stream.map(row => {
  println("row:" + row.toString())
  row
})
```

Some points are ...

- record type is GenericRecord
- readSupportClass is AvroReadSupport
- pass Configuration to fileStream
- set parquet.read.support.class to the Configuration

I referred to source codes below for creating sample.
And I also could not find good examples.
I would like to wait better one.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala
https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetInputFormat.java
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala

Comment: Do you know how to fix the `parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport not found` error at runtime? How are you running your job? It is included in my deps in build.sbt and yet spark can't find it.

Comment: Did you set parquet-avro.jar classpath at driver and executors?

Comment: My environment is CDH 5.6.x and parquet-avro.jar has already been included in hadoop lib dir.

Comment: hmm I downloaded and compiled parquet-mr and then included it on the classpath. Now I keep getting exception:
`org.apache.parquet.hadoop.BadConfigurationException: class parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport set in job conf at parquet.read.support.class is not a subclass of org.apache.parquet.hadoop.api.ReadSupport`

Think this is version mismatch?

Comment: In my case actually, I did not need to add parquet jar to build.sbt, assembly jar and runtime classpath manually. This seems to be because hadoop lib classpath had parquet jar and spark classpath had hadoop classpath. If you can't use parquet jar included in hadoop, you might as well make the same version between parquet in hadoop and built one at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parquet by adding some `parquet` specific `hadoop` settings :

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
var schema =StructType(Seq(
      StructField("a", StringType, nullable = false),
      ........

     ))
val schemaJson=schema.json

val fileDir="/tmp/fileDir"
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.read.support.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetReadSupport")  ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.requested_schema", schemaJson)
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(SQLConf.PARQUET_BINARY_AS_STRING.key, "false")
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(SQLConf.PARQUET_INT96_AS_TIMESTAMP.key, "false")
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(SQLConf.PARQUET_WRITE_LEGACY_FORMAT.key, "false")
ssc.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set(SQLConf.PARQUET_BINARY_AS_STRING.key, "false")

val streamRdd = ssc.fileStream[Void, UnsafeRow, ParquetInputFormat[UnsafeRow]](fileDir,(t: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) => true, false)

streamRdd.count().print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

This code was prepared with `Spark 2.1.0`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)