# How do I use fileStream to stream parquet files?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop2, parquet

I am trying to stream parquet files into Spark but I do not know how to use StreamingContext's fileStream method.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Spark Streaming Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) :

`streamingContext.textFileStream(dataDirectory)`

Spark Streaming will monitor the directory dataDirectory and process any files created in that directory (files written in nested directories not supported). Note that

The files must have the same data format.
The files must be created in the dataDirectory by atomically moving or renaming them into the data directory.
Once moved, the files must not be changed. So if the files are being continuously appended, the new data will not be read.
For simple text files, there is an easier method streamingContext.textFileStream(dataDirectory). And file streams do not require running a receiver, hence does not require allocating cores.

Comment: I want to stream parquet files, not text files.

Comment: fileStream supports many InputFormat. You
can use ParquetInputFormat. Check this out: https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/example

Comment: I don't understand how to use it. Do I need to create my own class like `Group` , and then my own `ReadSupport` for it, and then my own `RecordMaterializer` for it, etc.? 

I do not understand how the three types `K`, `V`, `F` work. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413552/how-do-i-read-in-parquet-files-using-ssc-filestream-and-what-is-the-nature)