# Using Spark fileStream with Avro Data Input

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, avro

I'm trying to create a Spark Streaming application using fileStream().  The document [guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) specified:

```
streamingContext.fileStream[KeyClass, ValueClass, InputFormatClass](dataDirectory)
```

I need to pass *KeyClass*, *ValueClass*, *InputFormatClass*.  My main question is what can I use for these parameters for Avro formatted data?

Note: that my Avro data already have schema embedded in the data.

I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413552/how-do-i-read-in-parquet-files-using-ssc-filestream-and-what-is-the-nature).  However theirs input is in Parquet format.

Comment: Avro support is not built into Spark like Parquet. I don't even know if this supports Spark Streaming.  https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

Comment: This would be the InputFormat, if possible. https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapreduce/AvroKeyValueInputFormat.html - and the Key and Value are entirely dependent upon what you wrote into the file

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you give an example on your last reply?  Also what if the the input data was text? Would you be able to serialize the data in the RDD?

Comment: Both options go to RDD. I don't know what your keys and values are... I was only answering what the Input format would be